# $(a_n \to a)\wedge (b_n \to b)$ with $a_n \leqslant b_n \implies a \leqslant b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> If $a_n \to a$ and  $b_n \to b$ with $a_n \leqslant b_n$, then how would I prove  $a \leqslant b$ ?

Have had some trouble with this and would really appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea:

We know , $a_n \to a $ and $b_n \to b$ implies $(b_n-a_n) \to (b-a)$[ the $\varepsilon/2$ 
argument]

Now $b_n-a_n \geq 0$. We have to prove $b-a \geq 0$. Suppose $b-a <0$. Then take $\varepsilon =|b-a|$ and use convergence of $b_n-a_n$ to produce a term  in the sequence $b_n-a_n$  which is less than zero!

**Added:** By definition of convergence, we can find an $N$ such that $$(\forall n \geq N):\;|(b_n-a_n)-(b-a)|<|b-a|=\varepsilon$$ In particular, this means $$|(b_\color{red}N-a_\color{red}N)-(b-a)|<\varepsilon=|b-a|$$ Which implies $$b_\color{red}N-a_\color{red}N <0$$ Contradiction!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still a bit unsure about how to show that $b_n - a_n$ produces a term less than 0. Can you please give a bit more explanation?

Comment: @HarryVulvi: See my edit